# Database AutoGrowth For Logging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, auto-growth

I have a SQL Server 2019 database that we use for collection of logs from our software from machines on our network. We are required to hold these logs for a about a year. With the logging from our collection scripts, it loads up one of our databases which is currently around 500,000MB. This is for our current network of 5 computers and servers. WE plan on adding many more computers and servers. As the network grows, I have a few questions.

1. As we grow our network what should we set our database Maximum file size to since best practice should not be autogrowth unlimited?
2. Currently autogrowth is set to 10% to unlimited size, should I change it?
3. If I set a maximum size with autogrowth to a maximum size will it not input data into the database once filled?
4. Should I turn on [Instant File Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver16) to help limit the size and is it worth the security risk?

I am trying to get a head of my network growing and figure out what I will need to do to manage the growth.

Comment: With regards to point 4, instant file init. is only applicable for sql 2022 onwards (or azure instances - but it sounds like you're talking about your own managed instances?)

Comment: Have you already cycled around more than one year's worth of logging, and set up some kind of archiving/purging of the records that are older than the required hold age?  To ask what the maximum file size should be is very much a "how long/piece of string" question.  We don't know what other databases are on the same server that will consume space, we don't know what your total available space is, we don't know how easy it is for additional disk space to be allocated

Comment: For point 3 - yes, if you have a maximum file size set, and the file gets to that size and is 100% used, requests to SQL that require more space will fail and ultimately the underlying error will be that sufficient space cannot be allocated.  For me, personally, I would always go for a maximum size that is probably well beyond what any guesstimates might tell me I need, but then I'll ensure that there is sufficient monitoring alerts on the server for overall disk usage because you also want to have plenty of time to mitigate the risk of an actual disk running out of space

Comment: @Craig Wait, what? IFI [has been around](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175935(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) since SQL Server 2005 / Windows Server 2003.

Comment: My understanding is that if the file reaches its maximum you will get an error and a soft fail, but if the autogrow starts and the disk fills there is a RISK that you get a hard fail and a crash and/or corruption

Comment: @Craig I have to check but I do not believe we have collected a whole year yet. As far as I can tell we have collected since October. We have many more machines to add to the system and its looking like this specific database is going to be HUGE. I think I need to look up some information on archiving and how to access those archived in the event I need those logs.

Comment: @vonPryz - you're right, my bad.  It's IFI for transaction logs that only has recent support